# Link doesn't work on AWS with Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I built a program to go on a website and click a link which automatically downloads a file. It works when I run it on my mac (Chrome), but when I use the exact same code on AWS, nothing gets downloaded.

If it helps at all, I tried to expedite the process and found the raw link, I could download that via wget but not through python (on any computer).

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that could happen. You sould check your logs and add them to the question. One thing I am sure in is that you don't use any virtual display, and you don't have a display on AWS. So you should google for "python running selenium headless"